# Video tool with text to speech and video editor (synchronize feature)

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation

I need a video tool in which has the following features. Could you please help to find the best vendor who offers the below features at the best rate.

1. Convert text into speech.
2. Screen recording feature with high resolution.
3. Video Editor (synchronize the audio and video file).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For audio/video synchroniziation check out Pluraleyes. 
https://www.redgiant.com/products/shooter-pluraleyes/
If you are a student at a film school they offer better prices.

I recommend reading the manual carefully and watching the vendor's video tutorials before going for the trial version and then deciding on the purchase.